# AI (Internal): Reached message limit. End of EventSource error messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I am performing activities as EventHubTrigger with Azure Function.

This trace message is popping up all over our AppInsights instance. I don't know what is means, or what could be the cause. I'm happy to provide any details that can help debug.

Trace message

> 2019-01-24T04:12:33.467   AI (Internal): Reached message limit. End of EventSource error messages.

sdkVersion : dotnet:2.7.2-23439

> 2019-01-24T04:12:33.467   AI (Internal): [Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Core] Reached message limit. End of EventSource error messages.

sdkVersion : dotnet:2.8.1-22898

Comment: Please try to downgrade you application insight version to 2.7.2 or lower. It is just trying to record the internal error message. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT I have downgrade package version to 2.7.2 from 2.8.1.
Lets see the result.

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: In monitoring face @MohitVerma-MSFT

Comment: Hi Rahul, Did it worked for you?

Comment: As of now no exception coming with application insight 2.7.2. Still I am in under observation. But I am feeling application insight 2.8.1 is not stable one.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Azure Functions offers [built-in integration][1] with Application Insights, which is available through the ILogger Interface. Below is the list of currently supported features. Review Azure Functions' [guide][2] for Getting started.
```

---

[image]