# EventSourceException while processing event "DiagnosticsEventThrottlingHasBeenResetForTheEvent"

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-eventhub

Performing activities as EventHubTrigger with Azure Function.

This trace message is popping up all over our AppInsights instance. I don't know what is means, or what could be the cause. I'm happy to provide any details that can help debug.

> AI (Internal): [Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Core] EventSourceException while processing event "DiagnosticsEventThrottlingHasBeenResetForTheEvent": System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

sdkVersion : dotnet:2.8.1-22898

> AI (Internal): EventSourceException while processing event "DiagnosticsEventThrottlingHasBeenResetForTheEvent": System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

sdkVersion : dotnet:2.7.2-23439

Code Sample

```
[FunctionName("UpdateFunction")]
public async static Task Run(
    [EventHubTrigger("Product-events", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")]Message[] objMessage,
    [Blob("%ProductBlobContainerName%", System.IO.FileAccess.Read, Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer productblobContainer,
    [CosmosDB(databaseName: "DatabaseName", collectionName: "procudtCollectionName", ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConnectionString")]DocumentClient client,
    ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
{
    TelemetryClient telemetry = TelemetryCreation.Instantiate(context);
    ConcurrentBag<int> DocumentToInsert= new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    ConcurrentBag<Message> DocumentToBeDeleted = new ConcurrentBag<Message>();
    try
    {
        telemetry.TrackTrace($"{context.FunctionName} Started", SeverityLevel.Information, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {
                "PrefixName",
                objMessage[0].ToString()
            },
            {
                "NumberOfMsgs",
                objMessage.Length.ToString()
            }
        });

        await UpsertProvider(objMessage, productblobContainer, client, telemetry, DocumentToInsert, DocumentToBeDeleted);
        if (DocumentToBeDeleted.Count > 0)
        {
            DeleteProviders.DeleteProvider(DocumentToBeDeleted.ToArray(), client, context, telemetry);
        }

        telemetry.TrackTrace($"{context.FunctionName} Completed", SeverityLevel.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        telemetry.TrackException(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Azure Background Function Name",context.FunctionName },
            { "Read Data from container > folder",  productblobContainer.ToString() + ">" + objMessage[0].PrefixName.ToString()},
            { "Total Documents received", objMessage.Length.ToString() },
            { "Number of documents to insert", DocumentToInsert.Count.ToString() },
             { "List of Documents to be updated", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocumentToInsert).ToString() },
            { "Number of documents skipped (Location is null)", DocumentToBeDeleted.Count.ToString() },
            { "List of Documents skipped", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DocumentToBeDeleted).ToString() },
            { "Exception Message",ex.Message },
            { "Exception InnerMessage",ex.InnerException.ToString() }
            });

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This thread seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347532/ai-internal-reached-message-limit-end-of-eventsource-error-messages/54418336#54418336 . Please try downgrading the application insight version to 2.7.2 as it works well with  Azure function V2.

Comment: I have downgraded the solution with 2.7.2.As of now no exception coming with application insight 2.7.2. Still I am in under observation. But I am feeling application insight 2.8.1 is not stable one.

Comment: Alright, hoping it will not cause any issue further. Application Insight 2.8.1 is a stable release , it's just that it doesn't work well with Azure function V2. As per latest release on Azure function , suitable AI library is 2.7.2. Here is the link for that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-functions-supported-features

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT after 72 hours received error : AI (Internal): Current Activity is null for event = 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Stop' (right now AI 2.7.2). Any idea?

Comment: Apparantly , it happens when multiple app are hosted in same process and each app initializes its own AppInsights pipeline and multiple modules start working in parallel . There is a similar thread on this issue  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/1009